# NODEjs como receber uma lista ou fila em uma rota do tipo POST com json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

estou trabalhando em uma automatização, onde a ideia é passar um POST com dados para que a aplicação a receba e execute o script.

Até ai eu consegui realizar sem muitos problemas, porém a ideia é criar uma lista ou fila para a aplicação rodar mais de uma vez.

Como seria a ideia de implementar essa lista ou fila? Oque devo procurar, pesquisar e estudar para entender essa parte? Abaixo um resumo do código com as partes necessárias, caso precisem de mais alguma parte do código eu o disponibilizo.

ARQUIVO INDEX.JS

```
    require('dotenv').config();
    require('express-async-errors');
    
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
    const captcha = require('./normalCaptcha');
    
    const SECRET_CNPJ = process.env.SECRET_CNPJ;
    const SECRET_PASSWORD = process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD;
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    //chamada POST
    app.post('/', function (req, res) {
        try {
            //Variáveis que criei para receber os valores do lado do cliente
            const {
                cnpjPrestador, municipio, cep, numero, razaoSocial, inscricaoEstadual, numeroNF, emissaoNF, grupos,
                subGrupos, servicos, valorNF, issRetido, simplesNacional, dataReferencia, discriminacao
            } = req.body
    
            //IF verificando se todos os dados foi informado para preencher as variaveis
            if (cnpjPrestador && municipio && cep && numero && razaoSocial && inscricaoEstadual && numeroNF && emissaoNF &&
                grupos && subGrupos && servicos && valorNF && issRetido && simplesNacional && dataReferencia && discriminacao) {
                console.log('-->dados informados para declarar NF serviço tomado:',
                    ....');
    
                    /*Inicio da minha automação com puppeteer para realizar um processo automatizado  em um site.*/
    
                puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--start-maximized'] }).then(async browser => {
                    console.log('-->Iniciando o script');

... 
});
```

ARQUIVO EXPRESS.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('config');
const consign = require('consign');

module.exports = () => {
    const app = express();

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.get('server.port'));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    return app;
};
```

JSON PASSADO NO INSOMNIA (a ideia é que caso seja passado mais de um json com dados diferentes, e com isso entrar em uma fila ou lista para que o script seja executado mais de uma vez.

```
{
"cnpjPrestador": "000000000000",
"municipio": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rbNoMunicipio",
"cep": "13000000",
"numero": "000",
"razaoSocial": "seu ze mercadorias",
"inscricaoEstadual": "000000",
"numeroNF": "00000",
"emissaoNF": "00000",
"grupos": "11",
"subGrupos": "1102", 
"servicos": "110203",
"valorNF": "210000",
"issRetido": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblISSRetido_0",
"simplesNacional": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblSimplesNacional_0", 
"dataReferencia": "20042022",
"discriminacao": "exemplo discriminação"
}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer enfileirar várias atividades custosas por cliente. Para isso você deverá trabalhar com [sessões](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html) para associar cada atividade a seu respectivo cliente. Precisará usar um serviço de enfileiramento de mensagens como middleware onde numa ponta o script do servidor após receber do cliente o JSON o associa ao ID de sessão e o encaminha como mensagem e na outra ponta terá um serviço consumidor dessa mensagem que a lê e faz a automação e põe os resultados no enfileiramento de mensagens no sentido do servidor.

Comment: Então se entendi corretamente o que está tentando fazer procure por arquitetura de microsserviços e enfileiramento de mensagens. Se entendi errado desculpe-me.

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo dedicado a responder. Com certeza irei procurar um estudo nas áreas que você citou. Valeu demaisss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve alterar o formato do JSON que está enviando e a forma como lida com os dados da requisição. Se o corpo pode ser um array com mais de um registro, mesmo que passe só um registro, o ideal é que você já o passe como array para que você lide com dados do mesmo tipo sempre.

**Neste caso o JSON enviado deveria ser:**

```
[
{
"cnpjPrestador": "000000000000",
"municipio": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rbNoMunicipio",
"cep": "13000000",
"numero": "000",
"razaoSocial": "seu ze mercadorias",
"inscricaoEstadual": "000000",
"numeroNF": "00000",
"emissaoNF": "00000",
"grupos": "11",
"subGrupos": "1102", 
"servicos": "110203",
"valorNF": "210000",
"issRetido": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblISSRetido_0",
"simplesNacional": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblSimplesNacional_0", 
"dataReferencia": "20042022",
"discriminacao": "exemplo discriminação"
}
]
```

**e em casos com mais de um registro:**

```
[
{
"cnpjPrestador": "000000000000",
"municipio": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rbNoMunicipio",
"cep": "13000000",
"numero": "000",
"razaoSocial": "seu ze mercadorias",
"inscricaoEstadual": "000000",
"numeroNF": "00000",
"emissaoNF": "00000",
"grupos": "11",
"subGrupos": "1102", 
"servicos": "110203",
"valorNF": "210000",
"issRetido": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblISSRetido_0",
"simplesNacional": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblSimplesNacional_0", 
"dataReferencia": "20042022",
"discriminacao": "exemplo discriminação"
},
{
"cnpjPrestador": "000000000000",
"municipio": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rbNoMunicipio",
"cep": "13000000",
"numero": "000",
"razaoSocial": "seu ze mercadorias",
"inscricaoEstadual": "000000",
"numeroNF": "00000",
"emissaoNF": "00000",
"grupos": "11",
"subGrupos": "1102", 
"servicos": "110203",
"valorNF": "210000",
"issRetido": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblISSRetido_0",
"simplesNacional": "#ctl00_cphCabMenu_rblSimplesNacional_0", 
"dataReferencia": "20042022",
"discriminacao": "exemplo discriminação"
}
]
```

Já na forma como você deve lidar com esses dados, você deve alterar o seu código para lidar com arrays. Neste caso o body deixará de ser apenas um objeto e passará a ser um array de objetos. Então deve fazer o loop dele, seja com map, foreach, for... **neste exemplo vou usar o map**:

```
// Um loop pra lidar com cada registro;
req.body.map(register => {
            // Aqui você lida com cada item 
            const {
                cnpjPrestador, municipio, cep, numero, razaoSocial, inscricaoEstadual, numeroNF, emissaoNF, grupos,
                subGrupos, servicos, valorNF, issRetido, simplesNacional, dataReferencia, discriminacao
            } = register;
   // A partir daqui você faz o que tem de fazer com o registro
});
```

Comment: Cara, muitíssimo obrigado. Foi perfeitamente oque eu precisava. De fato eu ja havia mudado a forma de envio do json, mas no código eu quebrei a cabeça varios dias e não vi algo relacionado e fiquei travado. Tudo de bom pra você!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou maninho =] Fico à disposição, tudo de bom pra você também.